# How to Bind ListViewItem's ToolTip to a ToolTip of TextBlock inside its ContentTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, contenttemplate

I would like to bind my ListViewItem's ToolTip to its ContentTemplate's TextBlock's ToolTip.

I tried the following but it didnt work:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DoestMatter}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ElementName=Title, Path=ToolTip}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" ToolTip="Test"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

**The ToolTip's value is dynamically generated, here I just showed it as static string but actually it isn't, and that's why I need to bind it to the TextBlock's ToolTip.**

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine as it is... well, I had to change some `Binding`s to get it to work, but the main XAML is fine:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip, ElementName=Title}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            ToolTip="Test" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

[image]

However, one thing that I did notice was that it only works if you put your cursor directly over the `TextBlock` and *that* was not stretching across the width of the `ListViewItem`. To fix that, just set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip, ElementName=Title}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            ToolTip="Test" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You're right... the `ToolTip` was still on the `TextBlock`. Then you just need to update your `ToolTip.Binding` to *the same value that works on the `Text` property:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" 
                            ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Now you should see 2 tooltips, one when over the `TextBlock` and one when over the `ListViewItem`.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

@Ron, I really cannot understand why you are taking such a negative reaction to my answer(s)... you *really* should watch your attitude, because I am *trying* to help you and I don't feel that I deserve your bad attitude. So, to address your second, even ruder comment:

> 1. I said that the HorizontalAlignment is set to Stretch by default

Really? Where did you say that? In fact, you *didn't* say that, you said *The ListViewItem stretches on default*, which is something entirely different. As mentioned in the comment, I was stretching the `TextBlock` inside the `ListViewItem` with the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property, which *isn't* set to `Strecth` by default.

> 2. Who said that I want the Title as my ToolTip?

Nobody said that, but you did say *The ToolTip's value is dynamically generated*... so I can only image that you are `Binding` your *dynamically generated* `ToolTip`. *If* this is so, then you can simply data `Bind` that same value to the `ListViewItem.ToolTip` property as well.

---

UPDATE 3 >>>

In response to your last comment:

> I stick to my question from the beginning because I cant really explain the problem. I know whats the solution though I dont know the practical way. I want to bind to the `TextBlock`'s `ToolTip` Property.

Well sorry, but you can't do that in XAML because the `TextBlock` is declared in a `DataTemplate`. You can only access `DataTemplate` generated elements in code because they don't just exist until runtime... see the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to find out how to do that. So you'll have to find another way to achieve your goal and that's why I've been suggesting these other methods all along.

Comment: It does not put the ToolTip on the ListViewItem. You can remove the binding and it will work the same... which mean you didnt bind it. The  ListViewItem stretches on default but the content isnt (which is what I want)

Comment: I wasn't stretching the `ListViewItem`... I was stretching the `TextBlock` inside with the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property, which *isn't* set to `Strecth` by default. However, you are correct, there was still an error with the `ListViewItem.ToolTip Binding`.

Comment: 1. I said that the `HorizontalAlignment` is set to `Stretch` by default
2. Who said that I want the Title as my ToolTip? 
I am using TextBlockService to determine if the TextBlock is trimming. If it is, the `ToolTip` of the `TextBlock` is its Title, else its null. Because the `ToolTip` can be null I want to bind the `ListViewItem`'s `ToolTip` to the `TextBlock`'s `ToolTip` and not to the Title directly.

Comment: I am sorry about my attitude. Sometimes I forget that you (people) want to help. By saying `ListViewItem` stretches I meant the `HorizontalAlignment` is set to `Stretch` by default. About the ToolTip, you are 50% correct. as I explained in the comment above the `TextBlock`'s `ToolTip` is set to null when the `TextBlock` is not trimming and when it does, the `ToolTip` is the Title of the `TextBlock`. Because the ToolTip changes on runtime and it is dynamical, I want to bind to the `TextBlock`'s `ToolTip` and not to the Title property.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is regarding the `null` value... that's not a problem if you use the [`Binding.FallbackValue` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The problem is that the `ToolTip` is the `ToolTip` of the `TextBlock`. I cant break it and use it like I use `Text="{Binding Title}"`.
I stick to my question from the beginning because I cant really explain the problem. I know whats the solution though I dont know the practical way.
I want to bind to the `TextBlock`'s `ToolTip` `Property`

Comment: Based on your last update (update 3) which is the most important (atleast thats what I think) I do need to find another method. If I knew it from the beginning I could think on another methods. Thank you!